# How to create a multi-level XML file from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, tree

I have an array

```
$arr=array("A","B","C");
```

and I want to create a multi level XML from that like

```
<root>
  <error>
    <A>
      <B>
        <C>
          <D/>
        </C>
      </B>
    </A>
  </error>
</root>
```

and I have written the code as

```
$arr = array("A", "B", "C", "D");
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput=true;
$doc->LoadXML('<root/>');
$root = $doc->documentElement;
$errorgroup = $doc->createElement('error');
$root->appendChild($errorgroup);
foreach($arr as $erreur) {
    $missinggroup = $doc->createElement($erreur);
    $errorgroup->appendChild($missinggroup);
    $errorgroup=$doc->createElement($erreur);
}
echo $doc->saveXml();
```

but the output is only displaying `<A/>` in the XML inside error and not the rest B and C. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful.

> **Problem:** `$errorgroup=$doc->createElement($erreur);` I don't what you were trying to do with this line.

**Change this:**

```
$errorgroup=$doc->createElement($erreur);
```

**To this:**

```
$errorgroup=$missinggroup;
```

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/856781)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$arr = array("A", "B", "C", "D");
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput=true;
$doc->LoadXML('<root/>');
$root = $doc->documentElement;
$errorgroup = $doc->createElement('error');
$root->appendChild($errorgroup);
foreach($arr as $erreur) {
    $missinggroup = $doc->createElement($erreur);
    $errorgroup->appendChild($missinggroup);
    $errorgroup=$missinggroup;
}
echo $doc->saveXml();
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
  <error>
    <A>
      <B>
        <C>
          <D/>
        </C>
      </B>
    </A>
  </error>
</root>
```

Comment: @timukh Hope this one will be helpful.

Comment: Yes it is working! Thank you so much. I see where I went wrong now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I will, but there is a minimum time and before that the site is not letting me accept an answer. It is showing "you can accept an answer in 5 minutes". So I will after 5mins :)